# PDFBox reduce file size

Tags: c#, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to process the PDF files. But my problem is that the PDFBox has lots of dlls, and they are consuming lot of space - that is they are making my application to consume lot of space. I was using ItextSharp before, and it was too light(+-4MB). PDFBox consumes +- 40 MB. I only need PDFBox to read PDF files only. Is there a way to reduce its(PDFBox) size ? Like removing unused dlls ? It uses these dlls currently :

[image]

Comment: Well that's what you get for using a Java library in .NET: it has to bring in the entire Java runtime. What was wrong with using iTextSharp and what is wrong with having some (admittedly, quite a few) additional libraries? Do you have an application you distribute and want to reduce its installation size?

Comment: @chosenOn As far as PDFBox is concerned, you quite likely won't need Corba or Management functionalities. But the other IKVM DLLs may rely on their presence.

Comment: Why not convert your code to java? Then you won't need the IKVM dlls. The latest 1.8 version is 1.8.13, the latest 2.0 version is 2.0.4. The jar files are still big, this is because pdfbox can also do rendering.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I changed from ITextSharp because ITextSharp it's no longer free. Yes i want to distribute the App to users, but i do know that some users will give because of the App size - Why because they might not have enough bandwith/data.

Comment: @mkl - I will try to remove Corba/Management

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Because i am a .Net developer. I'm not familiar with Java code.

Comment: iText is smaller since it is a real .NET port and not such an "emulation". Didn't even know that such a possibility exists (but I'm a java guy so no wonder ;-).

Comment: @Lonzak it makes a lot of sense now. No wonder the it's(ITextSharp) very light.